# Can adjectives come with a noun directly?

Tags: adjectives, auxiliary-verbs, ellipsis

Can we say

> it is the data accessible by the system

or we must instead say

> it is the data **that are** accessible by the system

Comment: Yes, it's called a [reduced relative clause](https://www.thoughtco.com/reduced-relative-clauses-1211107). But I think it depends on the sound. If it doesn't sound right, don't reduce it

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll be going through the page you gave.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are correct in this.

To expand this answer, I am going to reference from the examples [here](http://thewindlike.blogspot.com/2011/11/reduced-adjective-clauses.html#.WUAnsevys-U)

There can be 4 ways of using the reduced relative clause, which is what your question leads to: Omit the relative pronoun, Reduce an adjective clause to a participle phrase, Reduce an adjective clause to a prepositional phrase, and Reduce an adjective clause to an appositive

> **1. Omit the relative pronoun**
>
> You can omit the relative pronoun from the adjective clause when it is
>   the object (A good rule to remember: If the word after the RP is a
>   verb, you must have the RP there. If the word after the RP is not a
>   verb, you probably don’t need it. )
>
> For examples, I will talk to a consultant. I met him at a party. I
>   will talk to a consultant whom I met at the party. I will talk to a
>   consultant I met at the party. We will start our project soon. We
>   finalized it last week. We will start our project which we finalized
>   it last week soon. We will start our project we finalized it last week
>   soon. However, you can't delete in this sentence. We can't finalize
>   the project yet. It is very complicated. We can't finalize the project
>   which is very complicated yet. We can't finalize the project very
>   complicated yet.
>
> **2. Reduce an adjective clause to a participle phrase**
>
> Adjective clauses can often be reduced to phrases, but the relative
>   pronoun (RP) must be the subject of the verb in the adjective clause.
>
> a. delete RP + BE
>
> For examples, The university that are investing on human resources
>   will sustain in the future. The university investing on human
>   resources will sustain in the future. The dean who was appointed
>   yesterday graduated in the UK. The dean appointed yesterday graduated
>   in the UK.
>
> b. delete RP + (Auxiliary Verb) and change the Verb to VERB-ING
>
> For examples, The students who do more research at home perform a lot
>   better. The students doing more research at home perform a lot better.
>   The students who experienced real working environment also learn
>   faster. The students experiencing real working environment also learn
>   faster.
>
> **3. Reduce an adjective clause to a prepositional phrase**
>
> Adjective clauses can often be reduced to phrases, but the relative
>   pronoun (RP) must be the subject of the verb in the adjective clause.
>
> For examples, Did you see the book that is on the table? Did you see
>   the book on the table? She hasn't finished her paragraph which is
>   about her best friend yet. She hasn't finished her paragraph about her
>   best friend yet.
>
> **4. Reduce an adjective clause to an appositive**
>
> For examples, You who are students should plan about your future jobs.
>   You students should plan about your future jobs. Piseth, who is a
>   curriculum developer, has been working very hard. Piseth, a curriculum
>   developer, has been working very hard.